# Blank MySQL error on shared hosting

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a little bit of learning on mysql, php and the like. I'm using a shared hosting plan so am quite limited from a settings changes point of view.

I am attempting to run a simple mysql select command through PHP, but all i get back is a blank error

```
<?php
$typeID = $_GET['tid'];
//variables for the database server
$server = "localhost";
$user = "codingma_rbstock";
$pwd = "M@nL%V{%RI+h";
$db = "codingma_rbstock";

//variables for the database fields
$itemNo;
$itemNm;
$itemDesc;
$buyPr;
$sellPr;
$quan;
$dept;

//database connection
//create connection
$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $pwd, $db);

//if the connection fails throw an error.
if ($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection Failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

echo "Welcome to " . $typeID . "<br>";

$sql = "select ITEM_NAME from stock where ITEM_NO='00001'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
    $res = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($res->num_rows > 0){
            echo "success";
        }

}else{
    echo "Error: " .$sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

echo $res;

?>
```

I have checked and it seems to be connecting to the database fine (I changed a few account details to see if that threw a different error and it did).

I am sure I am missing something completely obvious here! The below is the text output from the error;

Error: select ITEM_NAME from stock where ITEM_NO='00001'

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you please post the result of executing `SHOW CREATE TABLE stock` in your DB server?

Comment: Try calling you page like this: `http://localhost/yourpage.php?tid=3455`

Comment: Tell me if that way kind of work?

Comment: What are the field names of the table?

Comment: output of SHOW CREATE TABLE stock below;
CREATE TABLE `stock` (
 `ITEM_NO` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `ITEM_NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `ITEM_DESC` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `ITEM_BUY_PRICE` int(255) NOT NULL,
 `ITEM_SELL_PRICE` int(255) NOT NULL,
 `QUAN` int(255) NOT NULL,
 `ITEM_DEPT` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
@Hackerman - cannot call the page using localhost as it is a shared hosting account I am trying this on
@Dragos - field names above. 
Thanks all :)

Comment: Do you have any data in the table?

Comment: Did you try passing the `tid` parameter in the url, like on my previous comment...I think that your code expects a `get` parameter and you are not providing that parameter, ergo, your script gets an undefined index...end

Comment: Also didi you try running this query `select ITEM_NAME from stock where ITEM_NO='00001'` directly against your server in order to check that returns data or something like that?

Comment: @Dragos - Yes, in the one I am trying to call it has the item number '00001' in item_no, test in item_name and item_desc, 0 in the price and quan ones and boys in the item_dept one

Comment: @Hackerman tid does get passed, leaving the latter part of the url as view.php?tid=boys and that works fine, part of my code which tests that (echo "Welcome to " . $typeID . "<br>";) returns correctly.
I have just run the sql query on the database and got the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is in this line

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
```

you are doing a variable type check ( === ), the result of that comparision will always fail because, for as long as you have data in your table and your query doesn't fail `$conn->query($sql)` will not return a boolean value

[mysqli::query documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) says:

```
Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.
```

You are using here a SELECT, therefore a successfull result won't be boolean

Try switching to

```
if ($conn->query($sql) == TRUE){
```

Or even better remove that if completely

`EDIT`

The better approach for that part of the code is:

```
$res = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($res->num_rows > 0){
            echo "success";
        }

if ($res === false) {
    echo "Error: " .$sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: @Mikecul you are welcome. Please check the update, I added a small code recommandation.